# Ionic 3/ Angular 4: loop does not start

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I have this code:

```
    this.LocationTracking.startTracking().subscribe(data => {

    firebase.database().ref('campaigns/' + data.results[0].address_components[7].long_name).orderByKey().once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        var childData = snapshot.val();
        this.fileNamesArr = [];
        //The following loop does not start
        for (let key in childData) {
          if (childData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.fileNamesArr.push(childData[key]['storageFileName']);
          }
        }
    });
});
```

And I am wondering why the loop in there does not start. I figured this out when I tried to log inside of there. My goal is to get some of the children in the Firebase database and push them to an array. Does anyone know how I can do this, or start the loop?

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2 ios 4.1.1 windows 4.4.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.7.1
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
```

Comment: Can you show, what console.log(snapshot.val()) displays?

Comment: I was able to log this. It logs out the object that I am trying to traverse. I was not able to set this to a variable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use **[fat arrow function](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/arrow/)** here.Please try as shown below.

> What Are Arrow Functions? Arrow functions – also called “fat arrow”
>   functions, are more concise syntax for writing function expressions. 
>   By using arrow functions, we avoid typing the function keyword and
>   curly brackets, their {this} is picked up from surroundings, that
>   means we are no longer need to use bind function to change the context
>   of the function.
>
> The other benefit of using arrow functions with promises/callbacks is
>   that it reduces the confusion surrounding the {this} keyword. In code
>   with multiple nested functions, it can be difficult to keep track of
>   and remember to bind the correct this context

```
this.LocationTracking.startTracking().subscribe(data => {
    firebase.database().ref('campaigns/' + data.results[0].address_components[7].long_name).orderByKey().once("value")
          .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
            var childData = snapshot.val();
            this.fileNamesArr = [];
            //The following loop does not start
            for (let key in childData) {
              if (childData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              this.fileNamesArr.push(childData[key]['storageFileName']);
              }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Great.Please see the Update on my post.